# Re-size strings in batch

Tags: batch-file, console, cmd

I am trying to get text re-sized

Example:

```
set item1=hello world
set item2=test
set item3=F
```

And after all item variables has been set it will be re-sized to 8 letters max so they look like this after they are done:

```
"hello .."
"test    "
"f       "
```

How i want it to look att the end:

```
echo %item1%
hello world

echo %item1a%
"hello .."
```

Comment: I strongly encourage you to rename this topic to "Re-size strings in batch". Current title give the idea of something completely different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: list of variables to play with (just for convenience)
SET list=item1 item2 item3
:: Initialise items
set item1=hello world
set item2=test
set item3=F

:: Pad to 8 chars
ECHO Before...
FOR %%i IN (%list%) DO CALL ECHO(+%%%%i%%+
FOR %%i IN (%list%) DO CALL SET "%%i=%%%%i%%        "&CALL SET "%%i=%%%%i:~0,8%%"
ECHO After....
FOR %%i IN (%list%) DO CALL ECHO(+%%%%i%%+

:: Re-initialise items
set item1=hello world
set item2=test
set item3=F
:: Pad to 8 chars. Dots in last 2 chars if truncated
ECHO Before...
FOR %%i IN (%list%) DO CALL ECHO(+%%%%i%%+
FOR %%i IN (%list%) DO (
 CALL SET "truncated=%%%%i:~8%%"
 IF DEFINED truncated (
  CALL SET "%%i=%%%%i:~0,6%%.."
 ) ELSE (
  CALL SET "%%i=%%%%i%%        "&CALL SET "%%i=%%%%i:~0,8%%"
 )
)
ECHO After....
FOR %%i IN (%list%) DO CALL ECHO(+%%%%i%%+

GOTO :EOF
```

Simple enough.

Results:

```
Before...
+hello world+
+test+
+F+
After....
+hello wo+
+test    +
+F       +
Before...
+hello world+
+test+
+F+
After....
+hello ..+
+test    +
+F       +
```

`CALL`ing (and I'll put some spaces in to show how it's interpreted)

```
SET "%%i = %% %%i %% [some spaces]"
```

will execute, for %%i in (the list), eg:item2

```
CALL SET "item2=%%item2%%       "
```

Since this is `CALL`ed, it's executed as

```
SET "item2=%item2%        "
```

so padding item2 on the right with 8 spaces.

Equally, `CALL SET "%%i=%%%%i:~0,8%%" is interpreted as

```
CALL SET "item2=%%item2:~0,8%%"
```

and executed as

```
SET "item2=%item2:~0,8%"
```

assigning the first 8 characters of the result to the variable.

The only difference with the second routine is that it similarly sets `truncated` to the part of the value of the variable minus the first 8 characters. Therefore it will either have a value or, if the variable is 8 or fewer characters, no value. Therefore it will either be defined or not. If it is, then set the variable to the first 6 characters+.. If not, then pad to 8 as before.

And the display has `+` either end to show the start and end of the value. Terminal spaces are a little  difficult to see...